# Passing params to new controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I have a created a simple landing page to collect email addresses in a Subscription model.

On submit, the subscription is created and the user is redirected to a thank you page that routes to subscriptions/thanks.

I want to pass the newly created id to the thank you page, like subscriptions/:id/thanks, so I can access the newly created subscription for the thank you page.

Comment: Show your routes.rb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code not tested**

In the route file:

```
resources :subscriptions do
  member do
    get :thanks
  end
end
```

Then make a method in the controller which accommodate the thanks route.

```
def thanks
  # thanks code will be here
end
```

In your controller after processing the data redirect the user to

```
redirect_to thanks_subscription_path(@YourSavedObject), notice: 'Some message'
```

That is all to it.

PS: I don't like this approach. It is better to be decoupled a bit better than tossing the variables around. Far too much duplications.

**Routing Explanation**

I learnt all of the routing from here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html Fantastic source.

Cheers and Good luck mate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mr. H!

Here is what I did which seems to have worked well enough.  I don't really understand routing, so any comments appreciated:

in routes:

```
  resources :subscriptions
```

get 'subscriptions/:id/thanks' => 'subscriptions#thanks', as: 'thanks'

subscriptions controller:

```
def thanks
    @invite = Invite.new
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
  end
```

create action

```
if @subscription.save
        format.html { redirect_to thanks_path(@subscription), notice: 'Subscription was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @subscription }
      else
```

Comment: Your `thanks` method is in the Subscription controller that is why I use the `member` as a routing block.